# Recursive find and replace on Command Line with Special Characters

Tags: bash, shell, replace, command-line, escaping

Im trying to recursively go through a folder structure and update a bunch of pom.xml files. I want to only update my version number so I'm trying to be as exact as possible. What I want to change is:

```
<version>5.1.1</version>
```

to

```
<version>5.2.0</version>
```

Im trying to include the version tags to be sure I dont replace any comments or dependencies this same version number may appear on.

I think the characters like '<,> or /' are causing issues.

I don't have much experience with escaping characters like this on the command line so any help is appreciated.

I am on a Windows 7 machine but have Git Bash and Cygwin installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am either using a tool called "fart.exe" for this - if the replacement is simple. https://sourceforge.net/projects/fart-it/

If I need regex I use power shell. 
Here is an example (mix of batch-file and power-shell) which replaces a version string in all XML files:

[replace.bat]:

```
SET version=1.2.3
for /r %%x in (*.xml) do (  
    powershell -Command "& {(Get-Content '%%x') | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '(''version''\s?\:\s?'')(\d*\.\d*\.\d*)('')', '${1}%version%${3}' } | Set-Content '%%x'}"
)
```